# Self-hosted open-source sales/product analytics solution?

Tags: web-apps, self-hosted, crm, analytics, tracking

I have multiple independent sources(websites) of product I would like to track the sales performance. They are scattered on different platforms and technologies that I'm looking for a central unified solution for sales analytics.

I have all the single transaction data that I can access to.

Each transaction may contain multiple products.

I would like to gather sales data and analyze what's the best selling product from transaction records.

Many of the sales are manual order transactions, so manual data input involvement is required.

What I need is to be able to:

1. Manually enter each transaction entries into the database and group them into categories (eg. book, dvd, electronics, etc.).
2. Get insight about what are the best selling products of each category with a report.
3. If it can also analyze cross selling opportunity would be even better.
4. I am looking for a self-hosted free open-source solution to begin with. If the solution has a premium version, I can upgrade in the future.

Comment: Is there any way in which generic database-management systems and statistics software wouldn't meet your needs?

Comment: What do you mean by generic database-management systems and statistics software?  Could you give me an example?  This is something that I'll have office staff managing data entry input, and reading the stats.  Would like something user friendly.

Comment: [DBMSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) include things like SQLite and MariaDB. [Statistics software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statistical_packages) includes programs like R and SPSS and programming libraries like Python's statsmodels and scikit-learn.

Comment: For an open source solution, I'll look into R.  It's a programming language from what I read. Is there any out of the box solution?

Comment: If [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_\(feature\)) is what you mean by "out of the box", R is already out of the box. If you're looking for a GUI, try R Commander.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions I found:

1. Dataiku - self-hosted option available, unlimited usage with the free version.  It's very capable, with a bit of learning curve.  It's something I'll spend time learning in the near future.
2. ClicData - no self-hosted option, the free version come with 10 data refresh/update per month.  Easy to work with, easy to learn, flexible analysis options.  Perfect for small projects requires little dataset.  I can get analysis done in an hour after learning via their online video tutorial.

Both of them can import spreadsheet which I manually created.

Even though I was originally looking for open-source self-hosted solution, but I find that ClicData is probably what will work best for me.

The free tier of 10 Data refreshes will be good for my current usage of 2 small projects, with weekly spreadsheet data refresh.

Is there's any other recommendation, feel free to comment below.